# Logging into a site that has ReCaptcha

Tags: java, android, recaptcha

I am making an android application, trying to log in a site with POST requests. The problem is site is not mine and it has ReCaptcha on login form.

I tried implementing android SafetyNet API, made a verify request using the site's own site-key but normally, the site ReCaptcha key type is not set to 'reCaptcha Android' and thus it returns the error [RECAPTCHA_INVALID_KEYTYPE](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/safetynet/SafetyNetStatusCodes#public-static-final-int-recaptcha_invalid_keytype) so I can't verify myself using android SafetyNet API.

I was wondering if there is any other way to verify the captcha site serves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a WebView component and loaded the page that has captcha in it. Then I get the site-key from the existing captcha, deleted all components in the page and rendered a new ReCaptcha element using javascript.

When the user verifies captcha, I log the verified token to WebView console to be used in a further login POST request in my application. I get the token by overriding the onConsoleMessage method on WebChromeClient.

```
    // assuming theres a webview component with id 'webview'
    final WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            webView.loadUrl("javascript: if($('div.g-recaptcha').length)" +
                    "{" +
                    "var sitekey = $('div.g-recaptcha').attr('data-sitekey');" + // getting the site-key from existing recaptcha element
                    "$('body > *').remove(); " + // deleting all content of the page
                    "$('body').append('<div id=\"captcha\"></div>'); " + // a div to draw new recaptcha
                    "grecaptcha.render('captcha', {\n" + // render the new recaptcha element in 'captcha' div
                    "    'sitekey' : sitekey,\n" +
                    "    'callback' : function(response){console.log('captchatoken:'+response)},\n" + // log the token on callback
                    "});" +
                    "$('body').css('background-color','transparent');" + // for aesthetic purposes
                    "}");
            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // show the webview now since captcha is ready
        }
    });
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage consoleMessage)
        {
            String message = consoleMessage.message();
            if (message.startsWith("captchatoken:"))
            {
                String token = message.substring(13); // removing 'captchatoken:' part from console message
                // now this token can be used in a POST request for logging in
            }
            return super.onConsoleMessage(consoleMessage);
        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl(url_that_has_captcha);
}
```

Here's how it looks like in action:

[image: in action gif]

Comment: Hey Nice work! I'm getting error like this.  *Uncaught Error: Tried to get element with id of "%s" but it is not present on the page* , I'm getting captcha from this insta URL https://www.fbsbx.com/captcha/recaptcha/iframe/?compact=0&referer=https%3A%2F%2Fi.instagram.com&locale=en_US&__cci=ig_captcha_iframe . Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Thanks @Dnyaneshwar! I think the problem with yours is Facebook does not use regular JQuery and my code requires regular JQuery. I improved this solution on my repository and the improved version does not require JQuery. You might want to check it at [this link](https://github.com/yunusemregul/koubilgi/blob/c2e83844c4869c8417fcfe090ad081826cd3687b/app/src/main/java/com/koubilgi/api/RequestMaker.java#L198-L240). If you want to apply this new solution you will need to create [this file](https://github.com/yunusemregul/koubilgi/blob/master/app/src/main/assets/recaptcha.html) and read it first.

Comment: Also, you will need to manually put the recaptcha sitekey of what site you want to use this, into that [specific line in the recaptcha.html](https://github.com/yunusemregul/koubilgi/blob/master/app/src/main/assets/recaptcha.html#L12). You can get the sitekey by visiting the page that has recaptcha then opening developer tools, finding the div named g-recaptcha and copying the data-sitekey tag on it.

Comment: This answer doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The whole reason reCaptcha exists is to prevent automated systems from crawling or interacting with systems. So in this case, unfortunately for you, it is succeeding by stopping you from logging in to the website using an android app.

You should not try to bypass this because it could be against the website's TOS, and could get you into some legal trouble. Instead, seek a public API that the website provides to do whatever you need to do.

Also, making a verify request using the site's own site key will generally not work because reCaptcha only accepts requests for your key on specific domains.

As far as I know, there is no reliable way of bypassing the captcha. That is why the captcha is widely trusted and used by many big corporations.

Comment: I think verifying the captcha from a WebView and logging in from the WebView then using its session cookies on further GET, POST requests will solve my problem.